# Pascal's Triangle Proof

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Trying to determine a formula for the sum of the entries of the $n$th row of Pascal’s triangle, for any natural number $n$. Any proof will do as I have to determine $3$ different proofs.

-

So far, I've been working with a proof which includes Pascal's Identity and using combinations to produce $2^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Expand $(1+1)^n$ by the *binomial theorem*.

Comment: Is it sufficient enough to say: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 1^{n-k}1{^{k}} = (1+1)^{n} = 2^{n}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Induction using $$\displaystyle \sum_k x_{n,k} = \sum_k (x_{n-1,k-1} + x_{n-1,k} ) = \sum_k x_{n-1,k-1} + \sum_k x_{n-1,k} = 2 \sum_k x_{n-1,k}$$ starting at  $$\displaystyle\sum_k x_{0,k}=1$$.